# Is there a race condition when the kafka producer sends the message?

Tags: race-condition, kafka-producer-api

Kafka guarantees ordering "if the partition is well loaded".
The messages in the partition are processed in order when consumed.

But isn't it possible for a race condition to occur even when the producer is sending?
If that's the case, then I think the ordering guarantees on consumer are useless if you start from the backwards from the load.

In particular, many kafka producer clients default to "asynchronous".

- KafkaProducer (native java client)
- KafkaTemplate (spring-kafka)
- MessageChannel (spring-cloud-message)

So, my guess is that even when sending, if I don't send in a single thread (or don't use CDC), I will get a race condition.

I don't know many programmers who deal with this issue in depth.
Maybe I'm wrong?

I thought about making it synchronous, but it would be too slow and unusable.

Comment: Ordering is guaranteed only at the partition level, while sending messages to topics defined in the broker Producers in Kafka choose a partition for a message based on the configured partitioning strategy. By default, Kafka uses a round-robin strategy, where each message is assigned to a different partition in a cyclical manner. if you want to restrict the messages to be consumed in the order they are published it can be achieved by sending same key for all the messages